# How to correctly work with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some method which create a MySQL query based on user inputs in form, (it is PHP Nette Framework syntax but its really not important for this question).
Correct syntax how I call DB query looks like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = ? AND surname = ?";
return $this->db->queryArgs($query, ['Dante', 'Hickman']);
```

But as you can see this is hardcoded so nothing to do with forms.
To real form I create another method which collect data and I just call it:

```
$builder = $this->buildSearchQuery($searchParams);
```

and after this dump of `$builder` is
array (3)

```
  0 => "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = ? AND surname = ?" (60)
  1 => array (2)
    0 => "Dante" (5)
    1 => "Hickman" (7)
  2 => 2
```

This data are correct, it's based what I insert to inputs so there are no problem with method buildSearchQuery()
But let's describe this array:
`array[0]` is string of query with placeholders base on inputs, `array[1][0]` and `array[1][1]` are actualy data (or text) what user fill to inputs.
and `array[2]` is number of inputs filled in.

I'm sure you already noticed that number of inputs can be changed,
`buildSearchQuery()` method for 5 inputs will return something like:

```
  0 => "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = ? AND surname = ? AND favourite = ? AND notFavourite = ? AND random = ?" (60)
  1 => array (5)
    0 => "Dante" (5)
    1 => "Hickman" (7)
    2 => "Pokemon" (7)
    3 => "Digimon" (7)
    4 => "1122334" (7)
  2 => 5
```

So as you can see, about part "query" part `buildSearchQuery()` already return correct value, problem is with that values stored in `array[1]`, I'm not sure how I can foreach this to make $query like:

```
return $this->db->queryArgs($builder[0], [$builder[1][0], $builder[1][1]]);
```

with dynamic number of array.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: yep, but i need to script do this automaticly, to script place that $builder indexes based on how many inputs are filled.

Comment: Surely you would just use `return $this->db->queryArgs($builder[0], $builder[1]);`?

Comment: My god , THAT SIMPLE!...i had this with one extra comma and it didn't work! :( Sorry for question

Comment: @timclutton could you button this one up with that as an Answer?

Comment: @Drew No problem, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second element of `$builder` is already an array you can simply pass it directly as an argument to the function:

```
return $this->db->queryArgs($builder[0], $builder[1]);
```